# What does "WHERE id <> 0" clause mean in SQL?

Tags: sql

Query: `SELECT id, name, FROM users u WHERE **id <> 0** LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0`

What does the clause `id <> 0` mean here? Does it mean:

> id is less than zero or id is greater than zero

Comment: Did you execute the query to observe the result?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`<>` means "not equal" (it can also be written as `!=` with some DBMS)

Answer (score 5):

It means not equal and apparently I have to submit at least 30 characters for my answer.

Answer (score 3):

It means, "where ID is different from 0".

So, both greater than **or** less than 0.

Comment: Wouldn't it return results that are greater than **or** less than 0? :)

Answer (score 0):

it means that you are fetching all records with an id different than 0 (zero), I've sometimes used this just to check if some record is already saved (if the record has an ID it means is saved).

Answer (score -1):

It means only include results who's field `id` has a value of greater or smaller than 0, basically records that have non-zero `id`'s - but really this should not be possible, if it is then I'd recommend reconsidering your table designs.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible to have ids that are not equals to zero?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It was a generalisation, I admit that circumstance always has an explanation for something or other, but I would say that if it can't be 'identified' then it really (again, in general) has no business being persisted.

Comment: I still don't get your point, sorry. "Get me all rows where the value of the column ìd` is not equal to zero" is a perfectly legal condition. It's no different than `<> 42`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I'm not saying the condition isn't legal - of course it is; my _opinion_ is that one shouldn't really require it, unless you're persisting things that have an `id` field but that don't require it being filled with an identifier - which I would suggest (in general) isn't a _good_ idea for database-design. And if `0` _is_ a valid identifier within your design, then excluding it in cases such as this means constructing a query to exclude a single record - the 0 is the point here, not the `id`.

Comment: I kind of agree: `ID <> 0` is a code smell e.g. is `ID = 0` a 'magic' value which can be modelled better?